# Join and get Last record In another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Please consider this tables:

**FileSpec:**

```
id       Name         Extension
-------------------------------
1        Nima            xlsx
2        Arian           txt
3        Ava             doc
4        Eli             txt
```

**DownloadLog:**

```
Name         UserName         Date
---------------------------------------------------------
Nima           User1         2019-03-14 12:01:43
Nima           User2         2019-03-13 12:01:43
Ava            User1         2018-08-11 15:32:00
Ava            User2         2019-01-01 10:48:33
Ava            User3         2019-03-01 02:02:02
Arian          User1         2019-01-21 17:15:42
Arian          User2         2019-02-21 09:18:10
```

I wrote this query and it returns my desire result:

```
select id, name, Ext, (select top 1 UserName from DownloadLog d where d.Name = f.Name order by [date] desc ), (select top 1 [date] from DownloadLog d where d.Name = f.Name order by [date] desc )
from FileSpec f
```

as you see I must write 2 subqueries to return `UserName` and `Date` fields. Is there any way to write above query with `join` and I can directly last download user from `DownloadLog` table?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use row_number()

```
select a.* from
(select f.*,d.date,d.UserName,
row_number() over(partition by f.name order by d.date desc) rn
from  FileSpec f join DownloadLog d on f.Name=d.name
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply`:

```
select f.id, f.name, f.Ext, d.username, d.[date]
from FileSpec f outer apply
     (select top 1 d.* 
      from DownloadLog d
      where d.Name = f.Name
      order by [date] desc
     ) d
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` with `ties` clause :

```
select top (1) with ties f.id, f.name, f.Ext, l.username, l.[date]
from FileSpec f left join
     DownloadLog l
     on l.name = f.name
order by row_number() over (partition by f.name order by l.[date] desc);
```

FROM [TOP (Transact-SQL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55162145/join-and-get-last-record-in-another-table/55162183#55162193) :

> Returns two or more rows that tie for last place in the limited results set.

Comment: can you explaint `top(1) with ties` ? what is `ties`?

Comment: Your solution is nice , but `@Zaynul Abadin Tuhin` solution has better execution plan